# How can I find a value in the same record as the given value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to give MySQL a value and I want it to search records, find the record with that value and get a specific value in that same record(in this case **ID**)

> Example:
>
> |ID|Name|
>
> ID is "5" and name is "Lapino"

How could I pass "Lapino" to MySQL and let it search that record and let it return the ID?

Thanks,
L

Comment: The answer to "is this possible" is virtually always "yes".  Why don't you instead give an example of the records you are searching, the code you've written to try to accomplish your task, and ask specific questions about any trouble you're having with it?

Comment: Use SQL. That's **Structured Query Language** and it's used for querying data from a relational database tables. So exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: BTW this is very essential feature of all databases (relational, object, NoSQL etc.). What would be databases good for if this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute a `SELECT` SQL statement using a `PreparedStatement`:

```
Connection conn = /*defined elsewhere*/;
String name = /*defined elsewhere*/;

int id;
String sql = "select ID from MyTable where Name = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (! rs.next())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found: " + name);
        id = rs.getInt("ID");
        if (rs.next())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multiple rows found: " + name);
    }
}
System.out.println(id); // Yay!
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the record whos ID value matches that of your requested value? To find a record whose ID equals 1234:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a jdbc connection and then execute the required query using statements

```
    Connection conn =
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                               "user=vikas&password=123");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet   rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=some_val");
```